# How to inherit config from default build.yaml file for custom configuration

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-build, dart-build

Dart build.yaml [docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-build-with-multiple-configurations.) proposes this approach to build with custom configurations:

> If you need other configurations in addition to dev and release, you can define multiple `build.yaml` files. For instance if you have a `build.debug.yaml` file you can build with `--config debug` and this file will be used instead of the default `build.yaml`. The dev and release flavors still apply. `dart run build_runner serve --config debug` will use the dev_options in `build.debug.yaml`, while `dart run build_runner build --config debug --release` will use the `release_options` in `build.debug.yaml`.

With this approach is there any way I can use default configs from `build.yaml` and only override some configs or add new configs in `build.debug.yaml`. Is this supported in any way?